# How do I install wine on a 64 bit install of Ubuntu 20.04.1?

Tags: software-installation, wine

Most things I try(following mostly outdated tutorials online) come up with missing dependencies. Can someone please walk me through installing everything required?

Comment: What have you tried that has failed? Writing detailed instructions requires time and effort. Let's not waste anyone's time typing out a step-by-step that you've tried and failed. Can you provide some of the error messages you saw when trying to install wine? This might lead to a proper solution being offered.

Comment: This guide should get you up and running https://linuxhint.com/install_wine_-ubuntu_20-24/.  I’d guess you haven’t enabled the 32bit components that are still necessary to run on a 64 bit computer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) Then run `sudo apt-get install wine` .